# Can $n$ hyperspheres in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be placed so all $2^n$ partitions (in the Venn diagram sense) are realized?

Tags: geometry, spheres

For $n=3$ this would just be a standard Venn diagram, because it would contain 8 different regions corresponding to the various combinations of intersections of sets the circles represent.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? And should the hyperspheres be *unit* spheres, or can their sizes vary?

Comment: Their sizes can vary. My only intuition is to place the centers of the hyperspheres on a regular $n-1$ simplex and hope a higher dimensional version of a venn diagram happens

Answer (score 4):

Consider the $n-1$ coordinate hyperplanes, together with the unit (hyper-)sphere.
Take a point not on any of these $n$ surfaces, and invert with respect to it.
All the hyperplanes become spheres and the sphere remains a sphere.